# divide columns by name

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, tidyverse

I have a list of nodenames with an id number ("tranche"). I am trying out 6 different strategies identified by the number in the column name. I want to divide the "pl_sum" columns by their corresponding "clr" column. I want the results as addition columns in the same dataframe.

I assume it is some kind of apply function, or maybe a dplyr summarise_at function. But I cannot get it to work. I'll spare you my jumbled attempts at accomplishing the task.

```
  nodename    tranche pl1_sum pl2_sum pl3_sum pl4_sum pl5_sum pl6_sum  clr1  clr2  clr3  clr4  clr5  clr6
  <chr>         <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 AECC_CSWS         1   -255.   -255.   -255.     0         0       0   160   160   160     0     0     0
2 AECC_CSWS         2   -310.   -310.   -310.     0         0       0   161   161   161     0     0     0
3 AECC_CSWS         3   -218.   -218.   -218.     0         0       0   172   172   172     0     0     0
4 AECC_CSWS         4   -375.   -375.   -375.    81.7       0       0   227   227   227    18     0     0
5 AECC_ELKINS       1   -266.   -266.   -266.     0         0       0   160   160   160     0     0     0
6 AECC_ELKINS       2   -336.   -336.   -356.     0         0       0   161   161   157     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use `grep` to find the 'pl' column and corresponding 'cl' (assuming that both sets of columns are in the same order in the dataset)

```
plcols <- grep("^pl\\d+_sum", names(df1), value = TRUE)
clcols <- grep("^clr\\d+$", names(df1), value = TRUE)
df1[paste0(plcols, "_by_", clcols)] <- df1[plcols]/df1[clcols]
```

---

With `tidyverse`, there are multiple options, one way would be to `map2`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map2_dfc(df1[plcols], df1[clcols], `/`) %>%
     rename_all(~ str_c(., 'new')) %>%
     bind_cols(df1, .)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think the tidy answer needs the plcols and clcols definitions after the package libraries, however.

Comment: @otterdog2000 i thought, once i defined it, wouldn't have to repeat it in tidyverse